# Chrome Extension not giving current time of youtube IFRAME

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-api, html5-video

[THIS IS ERROR IN MY CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDyi2.png)

What I am trying to do is through extension I want to get current time of the video I tried.

```
var htmlVideoPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
htmlVideoPlayer.currentTime
```

but it is giving error.

Now look at this image

[WHEN SELECTING CLASS OF IFRAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty6bS.png)

It gives me the current time but I can't access it from my chrome extension.

It gives CORS error

Any way to get current time of youtube IFRAME video from some another website so I can use it in my extension

also used this function to get current time of the youtube IFRAME video from my extension.

this is my script.js

```
   setInterval(function() {
       if ($('document.querySelector(".video-stream").getCurrentTime()').length) {
        console.log("Video Time Exists!");
        
        var videoTime = document.querySelector('.video-stream').getCurrentTime();
        console.log(videoTime);
      }
      else{
        console.log("waiting");
      }
      
    }, 100);
```

and this is manifest

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":"MyExtension",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "NewExtension Coming soon",
 
    "content_scripts":[{
        "js":[
                "js/jquery-3.5.1.js",
                "js/script.js"
        ],
        "run_at":"document_idle",
        "matches":[
            "http://*"
          ],
          "all_frames": true
    }],

    "permissions":[
        "tabs",
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

Comment: You need to declare your content script with `"all_frames": true` or use `allFrames:true` in executeScript.

Comment: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube-nocookie.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://www.websiteiwant.com'). this is what I get

Comment: We need to see more of your code. Refer to [MCVE](/help/mcve) for instructions.

Comment: I've added some code, what I tried in content.js, I want to get the currentTime(); of Iframe video from my chrome extension

Comment: We also need to see how you run/inject/declare this code.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've added all my code above